# EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new() error using openssl crypto library with Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

Basically I am following the tutorial outlined here: 
    https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption
trying to encrypt/decrypt a string with open ssl.

I have my a main function that calls an encryption function, with the appropriate header files.

The error I am getting is "Error LNK2019    unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new referenced in function "int __cdecl encrypt(unsigned char *,int,unsigned char *,unsigned char *,unsigned char *)" 
    This makes no sense because I believe my libraries are linked correctly (no other errors existed before) .

I've tried playing around with Linking in the properties tab but all to no avail.

```
The encrypt function is shown below here:

#include "pch.h"   
#include <iostream>
#include "Global.h"

using namespace std;

int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
    unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{


int len;
int ciphertext_len = 10;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;  
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(); // this seems to be the problem line 



return ciphertext_len;

}
```

The Global.h file is here, and includes references to appropriate header files:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H


#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

int encrypt_function();



#endif
```

And the main file, which calls the encrypt function:

```
#include "pch.h"   
#include <iostream>
#include "Global.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int arc, char *argv[])

{

    /* A 256 bit key- in reality we need to generate this from a password we provide in a file encryption service*/
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";

    /* A 128 bit IV- in reality we need to generate this from a password we provide in a file encryption service */
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345";

    unsigned char *plaintext= (unsigned char *)"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    /* Buffer for the ciphertext*/
    unsigned char ciphertext[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];
    /* decrypted and ciphertext length value holders initialized*/
    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;



    return 0;
}
```

Error is found in the encrypt function, where the ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(); line seems to generate the error :

"Error LNK2019  unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new referenced in function "int __cdecl encrypt(unsigned char *,int,unsigned char *,unsigned char *,unsigned char *)"